# Send as alternative email address for same user

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2007

My company (myco.com) has just purchased another company. We have added their domain (newco.com) to Exchange and configured MX records etc. so that we can receive emails on that domain.

Certain users of my company (i.e. not from the new company) need to send emails from this newco.com domain but not on a permanent basis.

Can this be done with Outlook 2010 or do we need to create new users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done in Outlook only. You need the additional configuration on the Exchange side. You need to either create new users or create Exchange contacts and grant "Send As" permission for required users. After that you'll be able to select user mailbox / contacs as "From" in Outlook and send emails successfully.